# Proving that Planck's Law is dimensionally homogeneous

Tags: units, thermal-radiation, dimensional-analysis

I would like to know whether it is possible to show that Planck's Law is dimensionally homogeneous, as well as the steps taken to prove it.

$$B_\lambda(\lambda, T) =\frac{2 hc^2}{\lambda^5}\frac{1}{ \exp\left(\frac{hc}{\lambda k_\mathrm B T}\right) - 1}$$

Thanks.

Comment: What does *dimensionally homogeneous mean?* Furthermore, note that this is not a homework site, so you should try to change your question to make it more conceptually interesting.

Comment: That means that the equation has quantities of the same unit on both sides.

Comment: I know that this is not a homework site, just that I am studying physics now and came across this topic by chance, which interested me, hence I was wondering if I can prove that Planck's Law is dimensionally homogeneous.

Comment: Why is it called dimensionally "homogeneous" if the opposite would just be "wrong"?

Comment: How can this equation be anything *but* dimensionally homogeneous? You've got some arbitrary function $B_\lambda$ and some variables on the RHS; whatever the units work out on the right are the dimensions on the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unit problems can be tricky, especially if you start with SI definitions of unadorned fundamental constants.  My technique is the think in energies and lengths whenever possible:
\begin{align}
[\hbar c] &= \rm eV\,nm \\
[\lambda] &= \rm nm \\
[k_B T]   &= \rm eV
\end{align}
So the argument of the exponential, ${hc}/{\lambda kT}$, is dimensionless as required.

(Why must the argument of an exponential be unitless?  From calculus we get the equality $e^x = 1 + x + \frac1{2!}x^2 + \frac1{3!}x^3 + \cdots$. If $x$ is dimensionful we cannot add or subtract the consecutive terms in the series.  Same for logarithms.)

We should expect $B_\lambda$ to have units of power per unit volume, since integrating this spectrum over all wavelengths $\int B_\lambda d\lambda$ gives this total power per unit area emitted by the blackbody's surface.  We actually have
\begin{align}
[\hbar c] &= \rm eV\,nm && \text{(again)}\\
[c] &= \rm nm / s  && \text{(this gives us time in the denominator)} \\
[\lambda]^5 &= \rm nm^5 && \text{(remove factors of length from the numerator)}
\end{align}